# VBA XML Code/Not Running under Office 2013 and/or work network

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xmlhttprequest, serverxmlhttp

I modified this existing code to parse out some XML data from the national weather service feed. It runs on my home computer (excel 2007) without issue. It does not run on my work pc/network with excel 2013.

The following error is thrown.

> Run-time error '-2147012894 (80072ee2)':
>       Automation error

Any insight? network issue or 2007 to 2013 compatibility issue? I can resolve the feed within my browser without issue.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Variables
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim Req As New ServerXMLHTTP
Dim Resp As New DOMDocument
Dim i As Integer
Dim Wthr As IXMLDOMNode
Dim geo As IXMLDOMNode
Dim cell As Range
Dim fn As WorksheetFunction
Dim y As Integer
Dim x As Integer


Set fn = Application.WorksheetFunction

Dim Eff, Exp, et, severity As String
Dim splitstring As Variant


ws.Range("A6").CurrentRegion.Clear

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Get Weather Alerts
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Req.Open "GET", "https://alerts.weather.gov/cap/us.atom", False
Req.send
Resp.LoadXML Req.responseText

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Write alerts to worksheet
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
y = 1
For Each Wthr In Resp.getElementsByTagName("entry")
    i = i + 1


    severity = Wthr.SelectNodes("cap:severity")(0).Text
et = Wthr.SelectNodes("cap:event")(0).Text

   For Each geo In Wthr.SelectNodes("cap:geocode")
   splitstring = Split(geo.SelectNodes("value")(0).Text, " ")
   For x = LBound(splitstring) To UBound(splitstring)
   y = y + 1
   ws.Cells(y, 1).Value = splitstring(x)
   ws.Cells(y, 2).Value = severity
     ws.Cells(y, 3).Value = et
   Next x
   Next

Next Wthr

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: I'm not sure. The only thing that pops is a message box showing the automation error.

Comment: Step through the code using **F8** and see which line you get an error on

Comment: Not showing any errors, it will step through the code and then run.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` and then compile. You might just be missing a VBA reference.

Comment: thanks for the help. option explicit recognized two variables that were not defined but still stuck on the automation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the issue was ServerXMLHTTP. ServerXMLHTTP does not auto-discover proxy settings and my company uses a proxy script (I should have included this information).

The code runs if I use XMLHTTP. I believe the code used ServerXMLHTTP because of cache issues so I'm not sure if I will run into other issues.

Revised Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Variables
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim Req As New XMLHTTP
Dim Resp As New DOMDocument
Dim i As Integer
Dim Wthr As IXMLDOMNode
Dim geo As IXMLDOMNode
Dim cell As Range
Dim fn As WorksheetFunction
Dim y As Integer
Dim x As Integer


Set fn = Application.WorksheetFunction

Dim Eff, Exp, et, severity As String
Dim splitstring As Variant


ws.Range("A6").CurrentRegion.Clear

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Get Weather Alerts
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Req.Open "GET", "https://alerts.weather.gov/cap/us.atom", False
Req.send
Resp.LoadXML Req.responseText

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Write alerts to worksheet
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
y = 1
For Each Wthr In Resp.getElementsByTagName("entry")
    i = i + 1


    severity = Wthr.SelectNodes("cap:severity")(0).Text
et = Wthr.SelectNodes("cap:event")(0).Text

   For Each geo In Wthr.SelectNodes("cap:geocode")
   splitstring = Split(geo.SelectNodes("value")(0).Text, " ")
   For x = LBound(splitstring) To UBound(splitstring)
   y = y + 1
   ws.Cells(y, 1).Value = splitstring(x)
   ws.Cells(y, 2).Value = severity
     ws.Cells(y, 3).Value = et
   Next x
   Next

Next Wthr

End Sub
```